# How to have a nullable string value in Mobx-State-Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to create a model with a optional, nullable string value.
I've tried using both

```
  hint: types.optional(types.string, ""),
```

and

```
  hint: types.maybe(types.string),
```

Both results in error when I try to set a json object as to the object.
Works if I manually loop through the json object and set the null content to empty string "".

> Error while converting "jsoncontent" at path "content" value `null` is
>   not assignable to type: `string` (Value is not a string).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`types.maybeNull`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#maybenull) to have a type that can also be `null`.

```
hint: types.maybeNull(types.string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the following solutions to have a nullable string value in a Mobx-State-Tree:

```
types.maybeNull(types.string) // value can be null
```

or

```
types.optional(types.string, '') // should create empty string if value is not defined
```

Comment: when I do  "types.optional(types.string, '')" and from my server sends a 'null' and I apply that snapshot it will error out. Is that the expected behavior for this? If I use maybeNull then it seems to have no problems.

Comment: OP value is null. It is not «not-defined». `types.optional` will take a `null` value as a personal blow to an ego, thus refusing to `applySnapshot` (or patch) values with a defined model.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a helper function that allows you to simultaneously have optional and nullable types.

```
function nullOrUndefined<T extends IAnyType>(type: T) {
  return types.maybe(types.maybeNull(type));
}
```